# Slow lxml -- Opening XML file takes extremely long time

Tags: python, performance, lxml

I am trying to debug the following:

```
res_items = grequests.map(rs)
for num, res in enumerate(res_items):
    try:
        t1 = time.time()
        node = etree.fromstring(res.content, parser=utf8_parser)
        t2 = time.time()
    except:
        continue

    for item in node.xpath('v:Items/v:Item', namespaces=self.ns):
        do_something()
```

Doing the `etree.fromstring()` seems to take an exhorbitant amount of time:

```
DoRequests: 1.10175395012 | 
OpenXMLNode: 2.28242111206 | <== This
ParseNodes: 0.331529855728
```

Is there some alternative I can do to increase how quickly I'm able to build this node? I need to do this tens of thousands of time, so the program runs quite slow because of it.

Comment: are you doing multiple requests?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- yes -- please see updated question.

Comment: Was going to suggest grequests before your edit, what version of python?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham version 2.7

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- is there something like an iterparse I can use instead of having to get the `node` ?

Comment: you could try parsing using `.parse`, passing the urls and doing that asynchronously.  It should be faster than using fromstring